# Trying to reset clock schedule in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So I made a game using `python 3.9.5`, `kivy 2.0.0rc4` and `kivymd 0.104.2`. After "start" button is pressed it starts count down timer. Only problem is that when it reaches zero I want it to reset at 60 seconds again because when player gets back to it it restarts the countdown. For now I've managed to cancel clock schedule. It doesn't goes behind zero. After it reaches zero it stops. But i want it to reset at 60seconds and I don't know how. Here's my `python` code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import threading
import multiprocessing
import plyer
import ffpyplayer
from plyer import vibrator
from random import randint
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRound, MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty

class Begin(MDFloatLayout):

    def start_on(self):
        self.ids.to_start.source = 'icons/start_pressed.png'

    def start_off(self):
        self.ids.to_start.source = 'icons/start.png'
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Beginning1after'
        music = SoundLoader.load('sounds/start.wav')
        if music:
            music.play()
        myapp.begin1after.timer_sec(begin1after)
        myapp.begin1after.update_label(begin1after)

class Begin1After(MDFloatLayout):

    def timer_sec(self, *args):
        self.function_interval = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_label, 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.stop_interval, 59.5)

    def stop_interval(self, *args):
        self.function_interval.cancel()

    def update_label(self, *args):
        self.ids.timeri.text = str(int(self.ids.timeri.text) - 1)

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.begin1afterdup = Begin1Afterdup()
        screen = Screen(name='Begin1Afterdup')
        screen.add_widget(self.begin1afterdup)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

And here's my `kivy` code:

```
<Begin>:

    Button:
        text: "start"
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        size_hint: .45, .16
        pos_hint: {'x': .27, 'y': .3}
        on_press: root.start_on()
        on_release: root.start_off()

        Image:
            id: to_start
            source: "icons/start.png"
            size: 370, 370
            allow_stretch: True
            allow_ratio: True
            keep_ratio: True
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y

<Begin1After>:

    Label:
        id: timeri
        text: "60"
        pos_hint: {'x': .0, 'y': .4}
        font_size: 100
        bold: True
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot do like this?

```
def stop_interval(self, *args):
    self.function_interval.cancel()
    self.ids.timeri.text = '60'
```

Perhaps, you might want [on_pre_enter](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).